# Amenable group in C*-algebra

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Definition 2.6.1.** A group $\Gamma$ is *amenable* if there exists a state $\mu$ on $l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$ which is invariant under the left translation action: for all $s\in \Gamma$ and $f\in l^{\infty}(\Gamma),~\mu(s.f)=\mu(f)$. (Here, the $s.f$ is the function $s.f(t)=f(s^{-1}t)$).

**It is true that the class of amenable groups is closed under taking subgroups, extensions, quotients and inductive limits.**

I have do some checking of the exercises above, but I am not sure whether my checking are correct ( I think the definition is a little abstract for me). So could someone help me to verify the exercises above?

Comment: Yes all of those are true, (as long as you are assuming $\Gamma$ is a discrete group). There are additional details if you want to include all locally compact groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is too broad and requires a lot of time answer it, so I suggest you to take a look at section 13 p.117 in [Amenable locally compact groups. by Jean-Paul Pier](http://bookfi.org/book/1219823)